# C/C++ Dynamic or Static memory allocation?

Tags: c++, c, memory

Dynamic memory allocation in C/C++ happens through `malloc` and the static memory allocation ex: `int a[3];` its allocated after the code is executed.

But this code `int x[y+1];` only can happen after a value is attributed to y and this happens in execution time, so its static, dynamic or both? does the compiler insert a malloc in the machine code automatically?

Comment: Side note: `int x[y+1]` is not valid C++ (although most compilers support it), it is valid only in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a Variable Length Array (VLA). Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array

Technically, it is not legal in C++, but compilers often support it as an extension, but generate warnings when they are turned on. See
[Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c)

It is legal in C.

Comment: Pay particular attention to the footnote regarding its inclusion in C99 and subsequent relegation to a conditional feature that is not required to be supported (C11 Standard, Section 6.7.6.2 - 4) E.g., see latest free draft: [**Programming Languages - C, International Standard (Committee Draft N1570, April 12, 2011)**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

`int[]` is on the stack, while `malloc`'d or `new`'d things are on the heap.

VERY basically `int[]` gets allocated automatically when it is reached (where y is already known) and gets dropped when it gets out of scope. It is not everything already allocated at startup.

There are no hidden `malloc` calls or stuff, that is just how the stack memory works.

(I hope for an answer from someone who actually knows C/C++)